# Using VB.net code to take Text from a TextBox and use for an SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a funny situation where I am trying to pass a date (formatted as a String in `yyyy-MM-dd` format [i.e. `2013-08-01`]) to an SQL stored procedure within an asp.net webpage. I have the stored procedure set up, but now I have to pass the date as a parameter. The date I need is located in a separate SQL table, so I created a `TextBox` (we'll call it `endDATE`) that provides the date I will need AND that I can hide to make it invisible on the webpage.

The problem is that the `TextBox` is contained within a `DetailsView`, so I can't seem to access it for the stored procedure.

I'm thinking I should try to pass the String from the `TextBox` using VB code to the stored procedure. **How do I do this?**

Code of `TextBox`:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="LatestDate" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None">
     <Fields>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="MostRecent" HeaderText="" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False"
     DataFormatString="Daily: {0:M/d/yyyy}" ItemStyle-CssClass="boldbig" />
     <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="endDATE" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("MostRecent","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     </Fields> 
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Code of Stored Procedure [`date1` is the parameter I am trying to provide]:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="dbo.TheMgr_Total"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
       <asp:QueryStringParameter name="MgrName" DbType="String" QueryStringField="id" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="date1" DbType="String" DefaultValue="2013-08-08" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

*Update: Steve's solution looks good to me, but I was never able to get it to work. My project changed directions, so I am no longer working on this particular problem.*

Comment: Hi there, would you be able to post any code (e.g. the ASP.NET page markup and the VB.NET code-behind) which you have so far? I think this will let folks here provide more specific advice to your situation

Comment: If you need just some temp storage to read data from one place (table) and pass to another (SP) - you do not need a textbox, just use a variable of needed type (string, date etc.)

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters to a stored procedure is a very common task and it is well documented

```
Dim dateValue as DateTime
dateValue = GetDateFromDetailsView()

Using cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)
   cn.Open()
   Using cmd AS SqlClient.SqlCommand(cn)
       cmd.CommandText = "storedProcName"
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theDate", dateValue)
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Using
```

Of course, you need to replace the `storedProcName` and the `@theDate` parameter with their actual values
The only problem is retrieving the variable dateValue of type DateTime. Here I need again to suppose a lot about your page structure but perhaps the GetDateFromDetailsView could be written as

```
 public Function GetDateFromDetailsView() As String

      Dim txtHiddenText = detailsViewName.FindControl("txtHiddenText")
      return txtHiddenText.Text

 End Function
```